# How to best deal with circular import ImportError due to import statement in __init__ file

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-import, importerror

So I'm working on a rather big Python 3 project where I'm writing unit tests for some of the files using the `unittest` library. In one unit test, the tested file imports a function from another python package whose `__init__` file itself imports from the tested file. This leads to an `ImportError` during the unit test.

It is desired for the `__init__.py`  to import from the tested file `periphery\foo.py`, so I would like to know if there is a possibility to make the unit test work without removing the import from `__init__.py`

Since the project contains a lot of files, I created a minimal example that illustrates the structure and in which the error can be reproduced. The project structure looks like this

```
├───core
│       bar.py
│       __init__.py
│
├───periphery
│       foo.py
│       __init__.py
│
└───tests
    │   __init__.py
    │
    ├───core
    │       __init__.py
    │
    └───periphery
            test_foo.py
            __init__.py
```

The init file in core `core/__init__.py` contains the code

```py
# --- periphery ---
from periphery.foo import Foo
```

while `periphery/foo.py`, which is the file to be tested, looks like

```py
from core.bar import Bar

def Foo():
    bar = Bar()
    return bar
```

Finally, the unit test has the following structure

```py
from unittest import TestCase

from periphery.foo import Foo

class Test(TestCase):

    def test_foo(self):
        """ Test that Foo() returns "bar" """
        self.assertEqual(Foo(), "bar")
```

Running the unit test yields the following error:

```py
ImportError: cannot import name 'Foo' from partially initialized module 'periphery.foo' (most likely due to a circular import)
```